# Attach code when IFrame content button clicked?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a modal popup that shows an IFrame. The IFrame then points to an aspx that has a button. The button's class is schedule-submit.

When I click that button in the IFrame, I want it to close the modal on my page.

I tried this in the document ready of the page that has the IFrame:

```
  $('.schedule-submit').bind('click', function() { 
                closeEditModal();
            });
```

But it is not having any effect.

What should I do to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it from the `parent` page where you have the modal popup with iFrame:

```
var $MyFrame = $("#iframeid");

// You need to wait for the iFrame content to load first
// So, that the click events work properly
$MyFrame.load(function () {
    var frameBody = $MyFrame.contents().find('body');
    var btn = frameBody.find('.schedule-submit');

    btn.on('click', function() { 
         closeEditModal();
    });
});
```